# Why doesn't servlet filter redirect to /home, if request /login & isLoggedin is true

Tags: jsf, redirect, authentication, servlet-filters

I have two JSF pages and some managed beans and one filter.

Everything and the filter **works correctly**;
- User must log in.
- So user either go directly to `login.xhtml` or redirected to it if he seek another page (`hom.xhtml` in this case)
- Once user log in he can navigate through the pages.

The **Problem** will be explained after the codes below;

login.xhtml:

```
  <h:form>
     <h:panelGrid columns="2">
     <h:outputLabel value="name:"/> <h:inputText value="#{user.name}"/>
     <h:outputLabel value="password:"/> <h:inputSecret value="#{user.password}"/>
     </h:panelGrid>
     <h:commandButton id="btn"  value="login" action="#{user.login()}"/>
  </h:form>
```

home.xhtml:

```
<h:body>
   Hello #{user.name}. You are welcome
</h:body>
```

User:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class User implements Serializable
{
   String name; //Getter & Setter
   String password; //Getter & Setter
   Authentication authentication;

   public User()
   {
      authentication = new Authentication();
   }

   public String login()
   {
      if (this.getName().equals("user") &&(this.getPassword().equals("1234")))
      {
         authentication.setLoggedIn(true);
         FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
         context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("auth", authentication);
         return "home";
      }
      else
      {
         authentication.setLoggedIn(false);
         FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
         context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("auth", authentication);
         return "login";
      }
   }
}
```

Authentication:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Authentication implements Serializable
{
   private boolean authenticated; //Getter & Setter
}
```

Filter:

```
@WebFilter(value = "/faces/*")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter
{

   @Override
   public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException
   {
      //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
   }

   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException
   {
      HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
      Authentication auth = (Authentication) req.getSession().getAttribute("auth");

      if ((auth != null && auth.isLoggedIn()) || (req.getRequestURI().equals("/LoginFilter_Simple/faces/login.xhtml")))
      {
         chain.doFilter(request, response);
      } else
      {
         HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
         res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/faces/login.xhtml");
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void destroy()
   {
      //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
   }
}
```

---

I tried to add this feature to my filter:
- After user log in, he can navigate all pages except `login.xhtml`
- If he typed in the address bar `login.xhtml` he will be redirected to `home.xhtml`

I added simple code to the doFilter method so it becomes:

```
   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException
   {
      HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
      Authentication auth = (Authentication) req.getSession().getAttribute("auth");

      if ((auth != null && auth.isLoggedIn()) || (req.getRequestURI().equals("/LoginFilter_Simple/faces/login.xhtml")))
      {
         if (auth.isLoggedIn() && req.getRequestURI().equals("/LoginFilter_Simple/faces/login.xhtml"))
         {
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/faces/home.xhtml");
         } else
         {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
         }
      } else
      {
         HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
         res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/faces/login.xhtml");
      }
   }
```

Even code logic is intuitive and easy
It gives -> `HTTP Status 500`

---

**Update**:

The problem `HTTP Status 500` is due to calling `auth.isLoggedIn()` in the nested `if` while `auth` is `null`.

Updated `doFilter` to solve `null` problem: (but gives `This web page has a redirect loop`):

```
   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException
   {
      HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
      Authentication auth = (Authentication) req.getSession().getAttribute("auth");

      if ((auth != null && auth.isLoggedIn()) || (req.getRequestURI().equals("/LoginFilter_Simple/faces/login.xhtml")))
      {
         if (auth != null)
         {
            if (auth.isLoggedIn() && req.getRequestURI().equals("/LoginFilter_Simple/faces/login.xhtml"))
            {
               HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
               res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/faces/home.xhtml");
            } else
            {
               chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
         } else
         {
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/faces/login.xhtml");
         }
      } else
      {
         HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
         res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/faces/login.xhtml");
      }
   }
```

The browser open with:

> This web page has a redirect loop
>     The web page at
>   `http://localhost:8080/LoginFilter_Simple/faces/login.xhtml` has
>   resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or
>   allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is
>   possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your
>   computer.

Comment: 500 means that an exception is been thrown. Just find it in server logs (if your HTTP 500 error page somehow doesn't show it) and interpret it. Exceptions are usually already the whole answer at its own. If you're unable to interpret it, just update your question to include it. We are able to interpret exceptions and translate them in layman's terms so that you will finally understand the cause. You know, once you *understand* the cause of a problem, then the solution is nothing more than obvious.

Comment: Just one thought: If `req.getRequestURI().equals("/LoginFilter_Simple/faces/login.xhtml")` evaluates to true, it is still possible that `auth` is null, which would throw a NullPonterException in the next `if` of your filter.

Comment: @BalusC @w4rumy It was `null` problem. I updated `doFilter` (above) to fix it, but browser gives `This web page has a redirect loop`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your logic. Your 1st `if` will result in a loop if the user has already logged in. The following should work.

```
boolean isLoggedIn = (auth != null && auth.isLoggedIn());

// Check if the user is accessing "login.xhtml"
if (req.getRequestURI().equals("/LoginFilter_Simple/faces/login.xhtml")) {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
        // Redirect to "home.xhtml"
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/faces/home.xhtml");
    } else {
        // Otherwise, nothing to do if he has not logged in
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

} else {
    // For all other pages,
    if (isLoggedIn) {
        // Nothing to do
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
        // Redirect to "login.xhtml" if he has not logged in
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/faces/login.xhtml");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also solved it before reading yours. So I will append my code to your answer (If you accept) for other readers to see both. they are already equivalent.

Comment: @SalehFeek: in case they're completely equivalent :), perhaps you can save time and just keep it this way since it will only add redundancy to the answer. For future readers, it's better to be concise. :)

Comment: Another example can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526574/page-does-not-display-good-when-using-filters-in-jsf/14527439#14527439