# handleNavigation not working in PhaseListener

Tags: java, jsf-2, phaselistener

I have a PhaseListener to control the user access to some pages, if the user is not logged he is redirected to loginpage.

The problem is that my method handleNavigation is not redirecting the user.
It runs but does not redirect the user.

When the user types a url that should not have access, the method runs but he page opens without redirected to the login page.

What is wrong?

```
public class AuthorizationListener implements PhaseListener {

  public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {

    FacesContext facesContext = event.getFacesContext();
    String currentPage = facesContext.getViewRoot().getViewId();

    boolean isLoginPage = (currentPage.lastIndexOf("login.xhtml") > -1);
    if(isLoginPage)
      return;

    if(currentPage.indexOf("/rws/") != -1)
    {
      HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
      Object currentUser = session.getAttribute("usuario");

      if (!isLoginPage && currentUser == null) {
        NavigationHandler nh = facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
        nh.handleNavigation(facesContext, null, "loginPage");
      }
  } 
}

public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Hellow World");
}

public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
  return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
}

}
```

My faces-config

```
<navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>/*</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>loginPage</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

<lifecycle>
  <phase-listener>br.com.testes.filter.AuthorizationListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're executing the code during after phase of render response. That's thus after JSF has rendered and completed the response. At that moment, the whole HTTP response is *already* finished and completely sent to the webbrowser.

This is a point of no return. Your code is simply being too late in order to change the response.

Listen on restore view phase instead. Or, better, use a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info). A JSF phase listener is an overly clumsy tool for the job (it does not kick in on non-JSF requests and is triggered up to 12 times during a JSF request). A servlet filter is the right tool for the job. You can find a concrete example in this answer: [JSF page style missing when using login filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526574/jsf-page-style-missing-when-using-login-filter/14527439#14527439).

Comment: I was just looking at your [blog](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html) and here you are !

Comment: @Apurv: Thank you for the Shiro hint. Note that Shiro is also using a servlet filter ;)

Comment: Thanks, I see the error now. If I use the beforePhase method works fine.

Comment: Can also, but that's plain inefficient. The JSF view has been built and all backing beans have been constructed where applicable. This is a cost for nothing. Just perform the check before restore view, or better in a simple servlet filter *before* all the JSF works.