# How to identify if session has expired and current page

Tags: java, http, jsf, session, servlets

Using : Mojarra 2.15, jsf 2.0, Jboss 7.1

Hi,Im trying to implement in doFilter method session expired, but :

- If the current page is **index.html AND the session has expired** then let the user type username/pwd and click on ok button and be redirected to another page.xhtml

The problem is when user type username/pwd and ok button, I got session expired page instead of go to the right page.

```
if (httpServletRequest.getRequestedSessionId() != null && !httpServletRequest.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
                session = httpServletRequest.getSession(true);
                session.setAttribute("logedin", "0");    // public user               
{

   if(httpServletRequest.getRequestURL().toString().contains("index.xhtml"))
   {
        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(loginPage);
   }else
   {
         httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(timeoutPage);
   }
} else {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    chain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are working on JSF I suggest you use filter :
[Servlet Filter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426872/servlet-filter-not-working/17542438#17542438)

response.sendRedirect // Contains the relative path

**About the do filter :**  I assume you set the USER object attribute in a login method

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

      HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        if (session == null || session.getAttribute("User") == null) {
              response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/index.xhtml"); // No logged-in user found, so redirect to login page.
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res); // Logged-in user found, so just continue request.
        }
}
```

**Hibernate Authentification:** I had the same issue, I fixed it, by checking if the session is still available. Then when i want to work with DB, i just need to call *getSessionFactory().create* or *delete* ....

```
protected Session getSessionFactory() { // Accessible que par les classes
                                        // filles
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    if(!session.getTransaction().isActive())
        session.beginTransaction();
    return session;
}
```

Comment: I set user object attribute iin login method. but the problem is I need to render sessionexpiredpage.xhtml when currentpage is different from login.xhtml page

Comment: OK are you using hibernate ?

Comment: yep. Im authenticating by hibernate

Answer (score 0):

when user request for index.html and session is expired your filter send it to login form. user enter user/pass and click on the login button. the new request send to server.
your filter check condition. session is expired filter send user to login form again and again.
in filter you most add a condition to your conditions. if request recieve from index.html and session is expired and not any user/pass set in request or user/pass is no correct then hoto login form else goto page.xhtml.