# JSF tags not rendered after filter implementation

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I was working on a project that worked fine until I decided to implement filtering.
I followed [BalusC's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) post on  [JSF HTTP Session Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841361/jsf-http-session-login) .
Now, none of the jsf tags is rendered. Here is my web.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>UserFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>servlet.UserFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UserFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ImageServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/admin/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>blitzer</param-value>
</context-param>
```

When I remove the filters everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

That answer was based on FacesServlet mapping of `*.xhtml`. However, you've there the old JSF 1.0/1.1 style mapping of `/faces/*`. In other words, the FacesServlet is never invoked and you was just seeing the consequences.

You've 2 options:

1. Fix the filter to redirect to an URL matching your FacesServlet mapping.

   ```
   res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/faces/login.xhtml");
   ```
2. Change the FacesServlet mapping to `*.xhtml` like every sane JSF 2.x developer would do. This saves you from fiddling with virtual URLs all time.

#### See also:

- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why)
- [JSF returns blank/unparsed page with plain/raw XHTML/XML/EL source instead of rendered HTML output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112946/jsf-page-returns-plain-raw-xhtml-xml-source-instead-of-generated-html-output)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, if you intend to let the filter hook on a specific servlet, you'd better not copy its URL pattern like below:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UserFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Instead, you'd better map to the servlet name directly:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UserFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

And, it would also be nice if you followed Java variable naming conventions in filter and servlet names:

```
<filter-name>userFilter</filter-name>
...
<servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
```

Think of it as if you're doing like this:

```
UserFilter userFilter = new UserFilter();
```

Comment: Given the number of your answers that helped me, I can recognize any new one before even seeing the answer's author name :) thanks

Comment: I modified the web.xml file from /faces/* to *.xhtml. Now the page displays without css (neither default jsf css nor user defined).

Comment: That's a different problem. Your current problem is solved. In the future just ask a new question or search if it isn't already asked before, like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526574/jsf-page-style-missing-when-using-login-filter/